# Accessing user data in cloud storages implicitly

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, dropbox, cloud-storage

Assume a user uses my application to connect to an external cloud storage (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc) through OAuth2 - and I acquire an access token to his storage to perform actions on his behalf, with his full consent.

Assuming this is fully explained to the user prior to him proceeding with the connection, am I allowed to query, index and analyze any data that I'd like from his storage? (In the purpose of learning and providing him better service in the future)

Would that be considered a misuse of his access token?
Am I only allowed to access data that the user had explicitly asked to access himself through my application?

I realize I might be treading legal waters here, but I couldn't find any sort of validation in these type of storages' Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking only of Google as this is the only thing i have any knowledge of.

Technically you have access to the users data.  What you do with that access is up to you.  If memory serves if you are going to do any analytics on the data you need to inform the users of that.  And give them an opt out option although i don't know of anyone who does that or how they would detect if you are doing it.

Also in the google developer console there are two option on the consent screen.  Privacy policy URL and Terms of service URL I would suggest you fill them both out.  This should ensure you are on the correct side of  any legal lines by informing the users what you are doing.  Beyond that you may want to read the following two pages completely there maybe something hidden in there.

[Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/)  [Google API Services: User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy)

Comment: Thanks! Two things that caught my eye in the Google APIs ToS:
1. Prohibitions on Content
Unless expressly permitted by the content owner or by applicable law, you will not, and will not permit your end users or others acting on your behalf to, do the following with content returned from the APIs:
Scrape, build databases, or otherwise create permanent copies of such content, or keep cached copies longer than permitted by the cache header;

Comment: 2. API Limitations -
Google sets and enforces limits on your use of the APIs (e.g. limiting the number of API requests that you may make or the number of users you may serve), in our sole discretion. You agree to, and will not attempt to circumvent, such limitations documented with each API.

My conclusion:
It looks like there's a very gray area for analyzing user data (even without user's PII) there that I'm not sure if it falls under the first prohibition.
Also, the rate-limiting could also pose a problem by itself to do what I suggested to begin with.

Comment: 1.  Google likes gray areas then they can decided later that what you are doing is against the rules.   2. The drive quota's are very large you can check them in the google Developer console and some of them you can increase.